# Appropriate usage of "can't" and "cannot"

Tags: word-usage, difference, grammaticality, contractions, formality

Are there any rules for using *can't* and *cannot* since they mean the same thing, and they are used interchangeably, but they sound weird in certain contexts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer at ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78944/26446) suggests:

> Grammatically, you can use *can't* instead of *can not* or *cannot* in the majority of circumstances. There is an exception. In [wh-movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement#Wh-movement_in_English), the contraction should not be expanded unless you *also* change the word order:
>
> > *Why **can't** I have some bacon?* //OK
> > *Why **cannot** I have some bacon?* //not OK, archaic
> > *Why **can** I **not** have some bacon?* //OK again, although formal
>
> Stylistically, the choice between can't and cannot is more complex. Generally, people use *can't* in speech and informal writing, and *cannot* or *can not* in formal writing or very formal speech. Also, *cannot* might be used when you need to carefully distinguish it from *can't* in speech.

Answer (score 2):

I believe "cannot" is used in the more formal aspect, whereas "can't" is used in casual discussions and conversations.

Comment: I would just added that one should never use _can't_ in a formal written form.

Comment: In fact, we shouldn't be using contractions at all in formal writing.

Comment: _Never_ and _not at all_ are a bit strong; conventional wisdom is relaxing this restriction. [Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/contractions.aspx) says, _"Use contractions in formal writing if it will sound stranger to avoid them than to use them"._ The [Purdue OWL](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/purdueowlnews/516) opined that contraction use is _"sometimes dictated by what would otherwise appear as stilted language and over-formality"._ Even ELU evolved between [2010](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4871) and [2012](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93757).