# What is the difference between "Is it not wrong? And Is not it wrong?"

Tags: grammar, word-order, questions, negation, inversion

Recently I hear it a lot in different movies and it is bothering me a lot so I'll be pleased if you guys answer me

Comment: Which of the two do you hear in movies?

Comment: And in what movies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appropriate usage of "can't" and "cannot"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/879/appropriate-usage-of-cant-and-cannot)

Answer (score 3):

> <del>Is not it wrong?</del>

is, well, wrong ;) The correct word order is

> Is it not wrong?

What you may be hearing is the shortened version

> Isn't it wrong?

Comment: I disagree that the word order is wrong.  Poetic, yes; uncommon in spoken English, yes, but not wrong.  e.g, ["**Is not it** the case that if an industry is pretty profitable more capital will flow to that industry?"](https://books.google.com/books?id=fOpGAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA18-PA65&dq=%22is+not+it+the%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi98OLyw_j5AhUhlIkEHV3uBSsQ6AF6BAgKEAI)

Comment: @stangdon: Define "wrong". I find your cited usage hopelessly "non-idiomatic", even thought it's obviously *syntactically* "valid".

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Why are you asking me to define "wrong" but not the original answerer?  :-)  As for whether it's "hopelessly non-idiomatic", you can certainly find multiple examples of the structure if you look around.

Comment: [The way NGrams treats contracted forms](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Is+not+it+the+case%2CIs+it+not+the+case%2CIsn%27t+it+the+case&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIs%20not%20it%20the%20case%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIs%20it%20not%20the%20case%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIs%20not%20it%20the%20case%3B%2Cc0) prevents it being much use here. But Google Books has just a dozen instances of [Is not it the case](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Is+not+it+the+case%22) compared to *hundreds* of both ***Isn't it the case*** and ***Is it not the case***.

Comment: ...I already said they're all "syntactically valid". But what most *learners* want to know is *What forms do the vast majority of native Anglophones use?* And there's no doubt on *that* score.

Comment: Said Silver-Tree, “Troutie, bonny little fellow, am not I the most beautiful queen in the world?” - from Scottish fairy tale _Gold-Tree and Silver-Tree_ collected by Joseph Jacobs